# Undeclared identifier: 'PosEx'

Tags: delphi

I tried to use this code in my program in delphi 2007

```
function ExtractText(const Str: string; const Delim1, Delim2: string): string;
var
  pos1, pos2: integer;
begin
  result := '';
  pos1 := Pos(Delim1, Str);
  if pos1 > 0 then begin
    pos2 := PosEx(Delim2, Str, pos1+1);
    if pos2 > 0 then
      result := Copy(Str, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1);
  end;
end;
```

I did a search on google i've found  that i need "FastCode.Libraries-0.6.4.zip" i download it but don't know how to use it to make the code above works. please help!

Comment: What is the error? That undeclared identifier? Do you have `StrUtils` in `uses`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PosEx is defined in the `StrUtils` unit. Make sure to include it in your **uses** clause.

Comment: thanks a lot guys i've added StrUtils to uses and problem solved when i saw StrUtils i taught its SysUtils i think i shoult buy Glasses xD